# Where should I put 'use' keyword in my Codeigniter project to access it globally?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facade

Where should I put this code in Codeigniter to access it everywhere in my project?

```
use Authorization as Auth;
```

Comment: You can use it in MY_Controller & extends MY_Controller in every controller you create.

Comment: that doesn't work. I'm not even able to use it in extended controller

Comment: Where is located Authorization?

Comment: It is located in 'application/models' folder